# Microsoft Azure Oauth2.0: Invalid grant error with code AADSTS50131

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, office365

We have implemented Microsoft Azure oauth2 on our web app. For a particular tenant, while fetching access token using refresh token(grant_type=refresh_token), we are seeing below error. This app is working fine with other tenants.

Request:
https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/token

Response:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS50131: Windows device is not in required device state: domain_joined\r\nTrace ID: 93b98569-1c21-4f48-bee6-afa48aa73a00\r\nCorrelation ID: a52bb23c-dc2e-4fc1-83b7-b1d2a4d69e89\r\nTimestamp: 2017-06-14 11:20:06Z",
    "error_codes": [50131],
    "timestamp": "2017-06-14 11:20:06Z",
    "trace_id": "<masked>",
    "correlation_id": "<masked>",
    "claims": "{\"access_token\":{\"polids\":{\"essential\":true,\"values\":[\"06ae1081-33ca-489c-85fa-42e53fc90f96\"]}}}"
}
```

Why the above error is coming? What steps required to resolve it?

Comment: sounds like that particular AAD tenant uses `conditional access` policies to ensure device is domain-joined to use apps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-conditional-access-azure-portal

Comment: @iandayman: Disabling conditional access on user got rid of the above error. Is there a way to put our Azure Web App in exception list instead of removing conditional access from user account?